# Logic to prevent unauthorized change in CRUD in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to model a PHP in CRUD and am wondering what is the best method to check the user's authorization so they can only edit their own content?

For example:

```
abc.com/post/delete.php?id=3
```

How do I prevent a logged in user from editing someone else's post?

My current method is:

1. Store User ID in session after successful logged in
2. When requesting DELETE method, load User_ID from session
3. Query = DELETE FROM posts WHERE user_id = $user_id AND id = 3

In this way, if a user can modify the `ID` parameter, they cannot manipulate the stored session variable `user_id`.

Is this the correct method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest to use your logic but i usually store user id + access token

```
Access token is an hash for example sha256(username+lastname+registered_datetime); and i put it to cookie
```

So you'll have an extra security field , just check if auth token  is ok also  when user logs

Comment: @user2223224 ok let me know if any problem ;)